# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

That question is generic.

I can't understand because when i include a bit of javacript code, only for testing something in magento, the following error returns:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
```

Anyone could give me an exemple of how a testing code should be?

This is the code I tested:

```
$("a").removeAttr("href");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento use `prototype.js` framework.
So if you want to use jQuery to read an element.

Use `jQuery` instead of `$`

```
jQuery('a').removeAttr('href');
```

Comment: That's right
I tested it and it worked perfect.
Thank You Very Much

Comment: For me, if i move attribute to attribute set i am getting error like https://snag.gy/Nmgn6p.jpg can u help me to get out this error?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is probably because $ is calling prototype and you are trying to access a property of a jQuery object. You should use a jQuery.noConflict() to prevent this kind of issues in the future. There are several guides to achieve this with different approaches, use the one you are more comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks a lot
I'll find out more about what you said